# Excel VBA run query from SMS Access database

Tags: excel, vba

I tried to run a query from an Excel worksheet. Below is my code but I think I am missing something here it does not work. I think my problem is the SQL code. Any help?

Thanks

Baha

```
 Option Explicit
 Const TARGET_DB1 = "DB_PlayerMasterManual.mdb"
 Const CopyTarget_DB1 = "DB_PlayerMasterManualBackUp.mdb"

Sub DisplayRatings1()
Dim cnn As ADODB.Connection
Dim rst As ADODB.Recordset
Dim fld As ADODB.Field
Dim MyConn
Dim i As Long
Dim lastrow As Long
Dim cel As Range
lastrow = Sheets("RatingReport").Range("A1048576").End(xlUp).Row
Dim ShDest As Worksheet
Set ShDest = Sheets("RatingReport")
Set cnn = New ADODB.Connection
MyConn = "J:\Gaming Common\PlayerMaster_Manual" & "\" & _
"DataFiles\" & TARGET_DB1
 With cnn
.Provider = "Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0"
.Open MyConn
End With
Set rst = New ADODB.Recordset
rst.CursorLocation = adUseServer
rst.Open "Select CustName & _
FROM tblRating WHERE CustID='" &  _
CustIdTB.Value    & "' ", cnn, , , adCmdTable
ShDest.Activate
Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Offset(1, 0).Clear
i = 0
With Range("A1")
For Each fld In rst.Fields
.Offset(0, i).Value = fld.Name
i = i + 1
Next fld
End With
Range("A2").CopyFromRecordset rst
rst.Close
cnn.Close
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't seem to be defining `TARGET_DB1` anywhere. I guess it's the filename of the database. Perhaps that's deliberate or it might be a mistake. If a mistake, correct that. Assuming that's a Global or a Function you also have a slight issue with the building of your query over 3 lines:

Try changing:

```
rst.Open "Select CustName & _
FROM tblRating WHERE CustID='" & _
CustIdTB.Value    & "' ", cnn, , , adCmdTable
```

to:

```
rst.Open "Select CustName " & _
"FROM tblRating WHERE CustID='" & _
CustIdTB.Value & "' ", cnn, , , adCmdTable
```

---

UDPATE:

As per comment, try:

```
rst.Open " (Select CustName " & _
"FROM tblRating WHERE CustID='" & _
CustIdTB.Value & "') ", cnn, , , adCmdTable
```

Comment: Hello friend,thank you for the input. I defined that as a const. After I altered my code to your suggestion, I still got "Automation error"

Comment: I tried to mock this up myself and I noticed that using ACE (not JET) that the command text is automatically prefixed with "Select * from " so to only pick up your one column you'd need to create it as a subquery. See my update on my answer. I can't say if it will work for you due to the differences but it did on my mock up.

Comment: Any more help??

Comment: Actually I did.When I debug, it gives; Run-time error: '-2147217913(80040e07)':
Automation error 
on this line:
     rst.Open Source:="tblRating", ActiveConnection:=cnn, _
     CursorType:=adOpenDynamic, LockType:=adLockOptimistic, _
     Options:=adCmdTable

Comment: Sorry, I'm out of my comfort zone now. Hopefully someone else can help.